# DAV extension file length

Tags: c#, vlc, dav-file

I have written my own `.DAV` file player in C# for individual use. There is too much code to attach if I would have to explain what it exactly is. How can I get the `.DAV` file length in time to my player?

There is no meta-data like time-length for dav files in windows, and I can't find anything in Google. I will add that I can not count it on when file was created and as last modified. I was thinking about making a counter on file start in the player in seconds, but it is not what I mean. I would like to show how long the file is in time, and place it beside my progress bar like every player should look like.

My player is using VLC libraries.

Comment: maybe this link might help .. if not then you may want to post the portion of the code that deals specifically with the File / length https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5a92be69-3b4e-4d92-b1d2-141ef0a50c91/how-to-calculate-duration-of-wave-file-from-its-size?forum=winforms

Comment: Thank you. I will try to get as much information about codecs that are used for .DAV file and use this formula. I will give u feedback as soon as possible. Cheers :)

Comment: So i was trying to find information how could I use this formula for .DAV files but .DAV has video and audio so i couldn't find any solution. I will add my code as soon as possible to show you what you need just tell me what part of code would you need the most because no code has actually parts of getting the file time length.

Comment: If anyone was intersted in this question i have also open one on MSDN here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4f898bf6-6474-4ab6-92b9-9d23ccfaca67/how-to-calculate-duration-of-dav-file?forum=winforms# . I didn't solve it exacly but i have made a program that converts file from .DAV to .MP4 with as bad quality as possible so the file doesn't take much place and then i get time out of the converted file because file length stay the same. I use NRecoMediaConverter library to do it.